# Eslint Error: 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expression

When running the code below it throws an eslint error:

```
    handleColorChangeComplete(color) {
        const newState = {
            item: {
                ...this.state.item,
                color,
            }
        };
        const modFields = this.state.modifiedFields;
        if (!modFields.includes('color')) {
            modFields.push('color');
            newState.modifiedFields === modFields;
        }
        this.setState(newState);
    }
```

The issue seems to be with `newState.modifiedFields === modFields`.

How do I resolve this? Should I rewrite with a ternary operator?

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? You're comparing two objects and doing nothing with the result

Comment: `newState.modifiedFields === modFields;` doesn't do anything, hence why your linter flags it as a potential error.

Comment: I updated the code for more context. This is part of a handler function to update color state.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with `newState.modifiedFields === modFields;`?

Comment: You still haven't explained what you expect `newState.modifiedFields === modFields;` to do. The extra code doesn't make this any more clear.

Comment: The answer given is correct. Trying to do a boolean operation `===` without assigning the result is incorrect. Assignment is done via `=`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. `===` is a boolean operator, so `newState.modifiedFields === modFields` is an expression which returns `true` or `false`. If you want to set the value of `newState.modifiedFields` then just use `newState.modifiedFields = modFields;`

Comment: Thanks Matt. This is in a handle function to update color. I updated the code in my question.